# No need to specify that a question is [xxx-basic]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

5 questions under [php-basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-basic) tag.

10 questions under [ruby-basics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-basics) tag.

I don't think these two tags are useful to the questions, and they should both be burninated.

I wonder if there are more tags like this.

Comment: Agreed, burn them.

Comment: There are only two `[*-basics]` tags, and the other is [tag:jaxb2-basics], which appears to be legit. There are quite a few `[*-basic]` tags, but most appear to be related to variants of BASIC.

Comment: Someone is already working on this, I see. There are now 0 questions tagged [tag:php-basic]. So much for waiting for consensus. If they felt so strongly, why didn't they post an answer??

Comment: [xxxx-basic] was created after someone saw the tagging for visual basic and had consumed a bit too much [VB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria_Bitter) and [XXXX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castlemaine_XXXX).

Comment: visual-basic ??

Comment: @SeptianPrimadewa https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic

Comment: I though XXX was not a variable at first.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Both of these tags have been

[image]

Comment: Enthusiasm is great, however burninate-request are NOT about asking for help in acting, but about asking for **consensus** (and notably, potential objections) and about the best way to carry it out (re-tagging? synonym?...). Furthermore, should de-tagging/re-tagging be selected, it is best performed by 2K+ users to avoid clogging the review queue.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Hello, I'm sorry if this post was done incorrectly on my part, I have only participated in one of these before.  I did not take part in removing any of the tags or editing any of the questions, I simply noticed that all of the tags left had no questions left under them and so helped others to realise this by posting that it had been finished.  I understand a consensus has to be reached before this happens,  but do note that this post had 30+ upvotes with no-one against it and the tags had already been removed from said questions.

Comment: I have noted the 30+ votes, however I also note it was posted on a *Sunday*, where people might spend more time with their family than on Internet (WAT???). In general, given timezone differences etc.. Also, Shog9 posted clear requirements that a burnination request should fulfill (and which I can't find :(), and there's no tick list to indicate that they were even looked at.

Comment: @MatthieuM. People doing other things on a _Sunday_ (especially noting that it was Valentine's Day), a true surprise.  I believe the post you're looking for is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/270486) one.  Also, I must repeat that I took no part in doing any of the burnination, there is no way that I can (I have under the 2,000 reputation points required to edit a post).  I simply saw this request, thought I'd take a look at it, realised it was already complete and so told others so that they would realise the same.  If I did anything wrong, I can do nothing but apologise.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear; I am not condemning YOU particularly in any way. Maybe it would have been better if I had commented on the question instead :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. Ah. I was deeply concerned, wondering what I was doing that was so wrong.  Indeed though, I must agree with your point that it would have been wise to specifically be clear that all requirements had been met so that these requests don't get out of hand.  I feel this may have been a bit too quick as Cody Grey brings up in the comments of the question, but I'm not sure.  On the one hand, these tags should have almost certainly been burned, however on the other, there are scenarios in which this isn't clear, and we don't want to go rushing to conclusions.